# GCC 11.3 (possible) false positive warning

Tags: c++, gcc

Having the following code:

```cpp
int execute_lambda(auto&& lambda, int param) {  //
    return lambda(param) + 10;
}

int main() {
    int a = execute_lambda(
        [](int a) -> int {  //
            return a + 1;
        },
        32);
}
```

We use the following compile parameters: `-std=gnu++20 -Werror -Wshadow=local`

And we get the following warning (treated as an error, as requested):

`error: declaration of 'a' shadows a previous local`

I fail to understand how `int a =` variable is accessible to the lambda itself and why it is "shadowing" the `a` parameter from it.

Outside `a` is not captured nor accessible inside the lambda.

Could this be a GCC bug?

For convenience, here is the code, ready to be played with: https://godbolt.org/z/cdofvfaqx

Comment: whilst the outer `a` in `main` is indeed not accessible from within the lamda and the compiler won't be confused by the re-use of the name the puny humans reading it might be confused and it could lead to bugs or simply make your code harder to understand

Comment: @AlanBirtles: that is indeed true. But by that logic: "I saw `a` 20 lines above in the same file. I'm confused!" That, too, can enter the category you just described. It seems, to me at least, that this line is drawn in the sand arbitrarily.

Comment: The a  in `int a =` becomes visible and accessbile at the `=`-sign following the name. Uisng an `a` - any `a` - in the initialization of the first `a` is at least not the best idea. Like in `a = a + 1;` it is a plain error, in a lambda returning `a + 1` it might be legal, but at least it is not crystal clear what happens.

Comment: @BoP: I do not agree with that. Finding good names is already hard. Considering `a` a good name (for the sake of the example), it will be hard to find yet another synonym for `a`, just because GCC thinks it is confusing to be used twice.

Comment: actually it does shadow the name, you can still `decltype(a)` for example.